# Rcpp how to erase all memory used in C++ code after execution?

Tags: r, rcpp

I am writing an `R` program with computationally intensive parts written in `C++` via `RCpp`. However I noticed that the memory used by the `C++` parts of my program isn't freed after execution.

For a very simple example of what I'm talking about. Let's say I have a `C++` program and all it does is allocate 100MB of memory. In `R`, I write a for loop that runs this `C++` program 10 times. At the end of the for loop, I have used 1GB of RAM.

I expected at the end of each loop, that 100MB of memory allocated by `C++` should have been freed since the program has stopped running. However, that 1GB of memory is still around even though the `C++` program has stopped running. How do I get `R` to really exit out of the `C++` program and free up all the memory?

I know I should free memory within my `C++` program, but local variables cannot be freed. Even if it can, there are too many of these variables. The program written is meant to be run once, then shut down, then run again by a loop.

Thanks

Comment: Does the problem persist when you use `gctorture`?

Comment: even with gctorture it still persists.

Comment: Then it really seems to me like you'll have to free the memory manually. On Linux or windows 10 you can use valgrind to detect the memory leak. Also, local variables should be freed automatically according to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968662/how-to-free-resources-owned-by-local-variables)

Comment: You may have a conceptual issue here. Rcpp code is not a separate program, and its objects are part of R's memory pool _on purpose_. If you want tighter memory management you could do so on your own in your code but that is only suitable for moderately experienced C/C++ programmers.